# C# Looking to get obtain the <div> value using HtmlAgilityPack but receiving a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the value of the div class "darkgreen" which is 46.98. I tried the following code but am getting a Null exception.

[image: div]

Below is the code I am trying:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://rotogrinders.com/grids/nba-defense-vs-position-cheat-sheet-1493632?site=fanduele");
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='darkgreen']");
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
    }
}
```

If I run the same code but with doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rgt-hdr colorize']") it does pull the header data with no error.

I am thinking that maybe child nodes may be a solution but I am not sure as I am unable to get it to work still.

Comment: What values object and Eventargs are getting?

Comment: @Prateek , I don't think the eventargs is the issue here. Can you please remove your answer below? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the HTML your looking it is created by a javascript. And the HTML you load into your Document variable is pre-what-ever is created by the javascript. If you look at the page source in your web browser you will see the exact HTML that gets loaded in your HtmlDocument variable.

The example below will give you the data(JSON) that is used to create the table. I don't know whether that is enough for whatever you're trying to do.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program Started!");

        HtmlDocument doc;
        doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("https://rotogrinders.com/grids/nba-defense-vs-position-cheat-sheet-1493632?site=fanduele");
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//section[@class='bdy content article full cflex reset long table-page']/following-sibling::script[1]");
        int start = node.InnerText.IndexOf("[");
        int length = node.InnerText.IndexOf("]") - start +1;
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Substring(start, length));

        Console.WriteLine("Program Ended!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Alternative solution**

Alternatively you can use Selenium with PhantomJS. And then load the HTML from the headless browser into your document variable and then your xpath will work.

Comment: Kent, Thank you for the reply  I am trying this now. No wonder why I am scratching my head. I will update you shortly.

Comment: That was it! Than you so much!